# Add attribute_accessor to a single instance in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have the following code to add an instance variable to a single instance:

```
class MyClass
  def initialize(x)
    @var = x
  end
end

obj = MyClass.new(4)
obj.instance_variable_set(:@a, 5)
```

Can I dynamically add `attr_accessor` for the attribute so I can use `obj.a` and `obj.a = ...` or do I have to use `instance_variable_get` and `instance_variable_set` to get and set it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can send `attr_accessor` to the object's singleton class:

```
obj = MyClass.new(4)
obj.singleton_class.class_eval { attr_accessor :a }
obj.a = 5
obj.a #=> 5
```

or via:

```
class << obj
  attr_accessor :a
end
```

This doesn't affect other instances:

```
another_obj = MyClass.new(4)
another_obj.a #=> undefined method 'a'
```